# Unity 2D: Alter sprite anchor point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a plain 2D Capsule Sprite. I want it to rotate around a specific point instead of its very centre. In other programs, this point is called the anchor point. For context, I'm making a paddle for my 2D pinball game so obviously the paddle needs to move when you press a button, but I can't have it moving around its very centre... Well, I could but I don't want to.
So my questions are:
Is anchor point the correct term for Unity?
Can this be altered/moved and how?

Comment: A simple trick, though it can't be automated, is going into the Import Settings of the sprite you're using and clicking Sprite Editor, then, in the "Slice" tab, set a custom pivot point. The solution you shared is more flexible though and is how it is usually done.

Comment: I had a look for this and couldn't see it. Is this only for when I've imported an image as a sprite as opposed to creating a 2D sprite from the 2D object menu? E.g right click in scene > 2D Object > Sprites > Capsule. This is how I've made all my objects so far, nothing is imported. Other than that, thank you for validating my solution as a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's something you set specifically on images that you import as a Sprite. If you've been using the default sprite (I think it's simply white), then you can't change its import settings since it's built-in. If you add your own image in PNG or whatever to the project, you'll see its import options in the inspector when you click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ended up getting an idea from a friend who does this stuff too.
I made an empty game object. Made it the parent of my paddle. Moved the paddle to the point of the game object where I want the paddle to rotate around, and now when I rotate the game object, it rotates the paddle around the pivot point that I want it to have.
[Image of paddle, arrow pointing to the empty game object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Cky.png)

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Just works using UI components within a canvas

You can use the Anchor presets of the Rect Transform. Or define the Min/Max values for x/y coordinates in Anchors Property.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting. I added a Rect Transform component but it doesn't have presets like yours does. Best thing I could do was alter its pivot but this doesn't change where it rotates around unfortunately, it  still rotates around the centre of the image.

Comment: Your answer is assuming OP is using UI components within a canvas. However, he is using world objects with a SpriteRenderer attached.